# Unspecified error when trying to install SSDT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

I'm trying to install SSDT but I get the below error, for both versions of SSDT, either 2017 or 2015.

I did some research and someone said that it might be from the default browser and IE was blocking downloading the files. Changing to Firefox did not solved my issue and I tried to install `vs_intshelladditional.exe` and after this I get the same error. Any advice? Thanks

On the server I have installed SSMS 17.3 (Express) and Windows Server 2016 Essentials.

```
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Burn v3.6.3542.0, Windows v6.3 (Build 9600: Service Pack 0), path: C:\Users\entersoft\Downloads\SSDTSetup(1).exe, cmdline: ''
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Initializing numeric variable 'InstallLanguage' to value '1033'
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Initializing numeric variable 'EnglishLanguage' to value '1033'
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Initializing numeric variable 'INSTALLINTEGRATEDSHELL' to value '1'
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Initializing numeric variable 'INSTALLAS' to value '0'
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Initializing numeric variable 'INSTALLRS' to value '0'
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Initializing numeric variable 'INSTALLIS' to value '0'
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Initializing numeric variable 'INSTALLALL' to value '0'
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Initializing numeric variable 'SKIPENVIRONMENTSETUP' to value '0'
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Initializing numeric variable 'INSTALLSHORTCUT' to value '1'
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Initializing numeric variable 'TELEMETRYOPTIN' to value '1'
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\ENTERS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\sql_SSDT_1400_20171025105028.log'
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\Users\entersoft\Downloads\SSDTSetup(1).exe'
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Visual Studio 2015'
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Detect 45 packages
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Setting string variable 'devenv_DetectKey' to value '1'
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\14.0\premium'
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Setting numeric variable 'DEVENV_PROPLUS' to value 0
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Condition 'NOT DEVENV_PROPLUS' evaluates to true.
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\14.0\professional'
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Setting numeric variable 'DEVENV_PROPLUS' to value 0
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Condition 'NOT DEVENV_PROPLUS' evaluates to true.
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\14.0\enterprise'
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Setting numeric variable 'DEVENV_PROPLUS' to value 0
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Condition 'NOT DEVENV_PROPLUS' evaluates to true.
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\14.0\community'
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Setting numeric variable 'DEVENV_PROPLUS' to value 0
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Setting string variable 'devenvLang_DetectKey' to value '1'
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Setting string variable 'intShellLPInstall_DetectKey' to value '1'
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Setting string variable 'isoShellInstall_DetectKey' to value '1'
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Setting string variable 'isoShellLPInstall_DetectKey' to value '1'
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Setting string variable 'netfxfullredist_64_DetectKey' to value '4.6.01586'
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Setting numeric variable 'netfxfullredist_64_DetectKeyExists' to value 1
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Setting string variable 'netfxfullredist_DetectKey' to value '4.6.01586'
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Setting numeric variable 'netfxfullredist_DetectKeyExists' to value 1
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0\professional'
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0\professional\1033'
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VWDExpress\14.0'
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: File search: SearchForVWDEXPRESS_IDE_File, did not find path: \VWDExpress.exe
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Setting numeric variable 'VWDEXPRESS_IDE_FILE' to value 0
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WDExpress\14.0'
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: File search: SearchForWDEXPRESS_IDE_File, did not find path: \WDExpress.exe
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Setting numeric variable 'WDEXPRESS_IDE_FILE' to value 0
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Setting string variable 'SSASInstalledState' to value ''
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Setting string variable 'SSISInstalledState' to value ''
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Setting string variable 'SSRSInstalledState' to value ''
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\VC\Runtimes\x86'
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Setting numeric variable 'VSDEVENV' to value 1
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Setting string variable 'netfxfullredist_LangPack_Release_DetectKey' to value '394802'
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Setting string variable 'netfxclientredist_Release_DetectKey' to value '394802'
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Setting string variable 'netfxclientredist_LangPack_Release_DetectKey' to value '394802'
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\Packages\Package_for_KB2919355~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.1.14'
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Setting string variable 'netfxfullredist_Release_DetectKey' to value '394802'
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Setting string variable 'netfxclientredist_64_Release_DetectKey' to value '394802'
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Setting string variable 'netfxfullredist_64_Release_DetectKey' to value '394802'
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\Packages\Package_for_KB2919355~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~6.3.1.14'
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Setting string variable 'netfxclientredist_64_LangPack_Release_DetectKey' to value '394802'
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Setting string variable 'netfxfullredist_64_LangPack_Release_DetectKey' to value '394802'
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Setting numeric variable 'BootstrapperAction' to value 4
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Condition 'RebootPending = 0' evaluates to true.
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Condition '(NOT((proplus_DetectKey) AND (NOT(proplusLang_DetectKey))))' evaluates to true.
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Condition '((VersionNT = v6.1 AND ServicePackLevel >= 1) OR (VersionNT > v6.1))' evaluates to true.
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Condition '(netfxfullredist_DetectKeyExists AND netfxfullredist_DetectKey = v4.0.30319)' evaluates to false.
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Detected partially cached package: DEV14ISOSHELL, invalid payload: DEV14ISOSHELL, reason: 0x80070570
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Condition '(isoShellInstall_DetectKey = 1)' evaluates to true.
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Condition '(isoShellLPInstall_DetectKey = 1) OR (InstallLanguage = EnglishLanguage)' evaluates to true.
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Condition '(devenv_DetectKey = 1)' evaluates to true.
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Condition '(intShellLPInstall_DetectKey = 1) OR (InstallLanguage = EnglishLanguage)' evaluates to true.
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Condition '((netfxfullredist_Release_DetectKey >= 394254) OR (netfxfullredist_64_Release_DetectKey >= 394254) OR (netfxclientredist_Release_DetectKey >= 394254) OR (netfxclientredist_64_Release_DetectKey >= 394254))' evaluates to true.
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Condition '(InstallLanguage = EnglishLanguage) OR ((netfxfullredist_LangPack_Release_DetectKey >= 394254) OR (netfxfullredist_64_LangPack_Release_DetectKey >= 394254) OR (netfxclientredist_LangPack_Release_DetectKey >= 394254) OR (netfxclientredist_64_LangPack_Release_DetectKey >= 394254))' evaluates to true.
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Detected related package: {4EE99065-01C6-49DD-9EC6-E08AA5B13491}, scope: PerMachine, version: 14.0.1000.169, language: 0 operation: Downgrade
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Detected related package: {9D78F5D4-79D2-4FC6-AC56-F364A0ABC54F}, scope: PerMachine, version: 14.0.1000.169, language: 0 operation: Downgrade
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Detected related package: {4D2C56FF-7F36-4B49-A97A-24F0522D41D7}, scope: PerMachine, version: 11.3.6540.0, language: 0 operation: Downgrade
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Detected partially cached package: SQLASOLEDB, invalid payload: SQLASOLEDB, reason: 0x80070570
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Detected partially cached package: SQLASOLEDBX64, invalid payload: SQLASOLEDBX64, reason: 0x80070570
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Condition '(VCRedist2010Key = 1)' evaluates to false.
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Detected package: DEV14ISOSHELL, state: Present, cached: Partial
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Detected package: DEV14ISOSHELLLP, state: Present, cached: None
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Detected package: DEV14INTSHELLADDITIONAL, state: Present, cached: None
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Detected package: DEV14INTSHELLADDITIONALLP, state: Present, cached: None
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Detected package: DotNet46, state: Present, cached: None
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Detected package: DotNet46LangPack, state: Present, cached: None
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Detected package: adalsql13X86, state: Absent, cached: None
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Detected package: adalsql13X64, state: Obsolete, cached: None
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Detected package: SQLDOM13X86, state: Absent, cached: None
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Detected package: SQLDOM13X64, state: Present, cached: None
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Detected package: SQLLOCALDBX64, state: Absent, cached: None
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Detected package: SQLLOCALDBX32, state: Absent, cached: None
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Detected package: SQLCLRTYPES13X86, state: Absent, cached: None
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Detected package: SQLCLRTYPES13X64, state: Absent, cached: None
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Detected package: SQLCLRTYPES14X86, state: Absent, cached: None
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Detected package: SQLCLRTYPES14X64, state: Obsolete, cached: None
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Detected package: SQLSMO13X86, state: Absent, cached: None
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Detected package: SQLSMO13X64, state: Absent, cached: None
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Detected package: SQLNCLIX86, state: Absent, cached: None
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Detected package: SQLNCLIX64, state: Obsolete, cached: None
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Detected package: SSDTEXTERNALS13, state: Absent, cached: None
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Detected package: SSDT14, state: Absent, cached: None
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Detected package: SQLASADOMD, state: Absent, cached: None
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Detected package: SQLASOLEDB, state: Present, cached: Partial
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Detected package: SQLASOLEDBX64, state: Present, cached: Partial
[62E4:14B4][2017-10-25T10:50:28]: Detected package: SQLAMO, state: Absent, cached: None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, `LocalDB` was not installed as part of the initial installation of `SSMS Express Edition`. Installing the `LocalDB` and try again with the kit for SSDT downloaded from Microsoft website, worked smoothly.

Hope will help others!